# Pagination rules - HTTP response header to make next request

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a "copy data" activity making a REST call to get some data in json format. The data should then be transfered to a SQL database.

The problem is I can only get a certain amount of data for the specified HTTP request. For this I need to implement pagination rules, and I have tried to understand this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#pagination-support

The HTTP response returns the absolute URL for the next request in the header, with the field named "Link". As I can see in the documentation, it is supposed to be possible to get the value from "Link" and put it into a pagination rule.

As stated in the documentation:

**Next request’s absolute or relative URL = header value in current response headers**

It says supported pagination keys are **AbsoluteUrl**, with the value of this should be set like this:

**Headers.response_header OR Headers['response_header']**

Where the response_header is defined like this in the docs:

**"response_header" is user-defined which references one header name in the current HTTP response, the value of which will be used to issue next request.**

What I can't seem to understand is how this "response_header" can be set to reference the HTTP response header value of "Link".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the 'response_header' placeholder with your header name.
In your case - 'Link'

[image]

Or in code editor:

```
"paginationRules": {
   "AbsoluteUrl": "Headers['Link']"
 }
```